# Could not locate path for parameter 'petId' warning in eclipse KaiZen Open API Editor

Tags: openapi

Eclipse Oxygen 3a with KaiZen-OpenAPI-Editor (0.8.0.201905261858) shows warning when path parameter is specified in components -> parameters.

No such warning is displayed for query parameter.

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger for pet module
paths:
  /Pets/{petId}:
    get:
      operationId: getPet
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/petId"
      responses:
        200:
          description: pet response
components:
  parameters:
    petId:
      name: petId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
```

Following warning is displayed on line specifying name: petId:

`Could not locate path for parameter 'petId'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is an issue with KaiZen-OpenAPI-Parser, one of the related projects. I have submitted a [pull request here](https://github.com/RepreZen/KaiZen-OpenApi-Parser/issues/228) to fix the issue.

In the meantime, you can ignore the warning, or disable the Advanced Validation option in Preferences > KaiZen > OpenAPI v3 > Validation.